# Enterring meaningfully equal data to a HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

Friends, I found a question like this in HashSets.

```
public class _235 {
    private String s;
    public _235(String s){
    this.s=s;
    }
     public static void main(String[] args){

         HashSet<Object> hs=new HashSet<Object>();
         _235 ws1=new _235("ABC");
         _235 ws2=new _235("ABC");       

            String s1=new String("ABC");
            String s2=new String("ABC");

            hs.add(ws1);
            hs.add(ws2);
            hs.add(s1);
            hs.add(s2);

         System.out.println(hs.size());

     }
}
```

When I checked both ws1 and ws1 have added to the HashSet but not from s1 and s2 only one String has added. Since w1 and w2 have not gone through equal() I believe HashSet doesn't recognize them as equal 2 objects. But why doesn't this become same for Strings s1 and s2 as well. How it hs been identified they are as meaningfully equal objects. Please kindly explain.

Comment: To understand what happens, examine what `equals` and `hashCode` methods of `_235` do. Hint: it uses the superclass methods, when you don't override them.

Answer (score 2):

`HashSet` requires your custom class to override `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods which are used internally to detect duplicate elements.

`String` class has this implementation but your custom class `_235` does not have one.

**Note:** It is important to override both `equals()` and `hashcode()` and not just one of them or else results could be unpredictable when used with hash-based collections.

> You must override hashCode() in every class that overrides equals().
>   Failure to do so will result in a violation of the general contract
>   for Object.hashCode(), which will prevent your class from functioning
>   properly in conjunction with all hash-based collections, including
>   HashMap, HashSet, and Hashtable.
>
> from Effective Java, by Joshua Bloch

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java) with good explanation.

Comment: Does String classes's these to methods which had already written? Coz this gives the output exactly as three. :)

Comment: Yes String class has implementation for both equals() as well as hashcode().

Answer (score 1):

First of all String has overridden its equals method that checks for the content of it not through hashCode so when you add in the parameter of String "ABC" and other one "ABC" it will return true if the contents are the same.

String equals method:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
      if (this == anObject) {
          return true;
      }
      if (anObject instanceof String) {
          String anotherString = (String)anObject;
          int n = count;
          if (n == anotherString.count) {
              char v1[] = value;
              char v2[] = anotherString.value;
              int i = offset;
              int j = anotherString.offset;
              while (n-- != 0) {
                  if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                      return false;
              }
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
```

While on objects they only used the default equals method which use the hashCode of the object

Object equals method:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
return (this == obj);
}
```

In your result:

the `wsi` and `ws2` will always return **false** when executing equals method because they are located on different memory location while the `s1` and `s2` will return **true** when they have the same content thus only adding `one instance` of it to the `HashSet`, that HashSet does not allowed **duplicates**.

Comment: Oki.. So will it be same for other wrapper objects as well?

Comment: @user3789200 yes they have overriden equals method, for example `Integer` in its equals method it is only comparing the the int values